# Inner Join with streaming dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

So I have this streaming dataframe (gps_messages) in pyspark- 
 [image]

and I want a resulting dataframe to have same (all) columns but one record / row for each device_unique_id which has highest value for timestamp, so basically something like -

```
                                                              (MAX)
+----------------+-----------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
|device_unique_id|signal_type|latitude|longitude|elevation| Timestamp|
+----------------+-----------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
|       TR1      |loc_update |-35.5484|149.61684|666.47164|   12345  |  <-- *NOTE - please check below
|       TR2      |loc_update |-35.5484|149.61684|666.47164|   87251  |
|       TR3      |loc_update |-35.5484|149.61684|666.47164|   32458  |
|       TR4      |loc_update |-35.5484|149.61684|666.47164|   98274  |
+----------------+-----------+--------+---------+---------+----------+

*Note = only 1 record for TR1 from previous dataframe which had max value of timeframe among all records having 'device_unique_id'=='TR1'
```

so far, I have wrote this code,

```
gps_messages.createOrReplaceTempView('gps_table')
SQL_QUERY = 'SELECT device_unique_id, max(timestamp) as timestamp ' \
            'FROM gps_table ' \
            'GROUP BY device_unique_id'

# SQL_QUERY1 = 'SELECT * ' \
#              'FROM gps_table t2 ' \
#              'JOIN (SELECT device_unique_id AS unique_id, max(timestamp) AS time ' \
#              'FROM gps_table t1 ' \
#              'GROUP BY unique_id) t1 ' \
#              'ON t2.device_unique_id = t1.unique_id ' \
#              'AND t2.timestamp = t1.time'

filtered_gps_messages = spark.sql(SQL_QUERY)

filtered_gps_messages.createOrReplaceTempView('table_max_ts')
SQL_QUERY = 'SELECT a.device_unique_id, a.signal_type, a.longitude, a.latitude, a.timestamp ' \
            'FROM table_max_ts b, gps_table a ' \
            'WHERE b.timestamp==a.timestamp AND b.device_unique_id==a.device_unique_id'

latest_data_df = spark.sql(SQL_QUERY)

query = latest_data_df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode('append') \
    .format('console') \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

And it throws out this error -

```
raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;\nProject [device_unique_id#25, signal_type#26, latitude#27, longitude#28, elevation#29, timestamp#30, unique_id#43, time#44]\n+- Join Inner, ((device_unique_id#25 = unique_id#43) && (timestamp#30 = time#44))\n   :- SubqueryAlias `t2`\n   :  +- SubqueryAlias `gps_table`\n   :     +- Project [json#23.device_unique_id AS device_unique_id#25, json#23.signal_type AS signal_type#26, json#23.latitude AS latitude#27, json#23.longitude AS longitude#28, json#23.elevation AS elevation#29, json#23.timestamp AS timestamp#30]\n   :        +- Project [jsontostructs(StructField(device_unique_id,StringType,true), StructField(signal_type,StringType,true), StructField(latitude,StringType,true), StructField(longitude,StringType,true), StructField(elevation,StringType,true), StructField(timestamp,StringType,true), value#21, Some(Asia/Kolkata)) AS json#23]\n   :           +- Project [cast(value#8 as string) AS value#21]\n   :              +- StreamingRelationV2 org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@49a5cdc2, kafka, Map(subscribe -> gpx_points_input, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> 172.17.9.26:9092), [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@611544,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(subscribe -> gpx_points_input, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> 172.17.9.26:9092),None), kafka, [key#0, value#1, topic#2, partition#3, offset#4L, timestamp#5, timestampType#6]\n   +- SubqueryAlias `t1`\n      +- Aggregate [device_unique_id#25], [device_unique_id#25 AS unique_id#43, max(timestamp#30) AS time#44]\n         +- SubqueryAlias `t1`\n            +- SubqueryAlias `gps_table`\n               +- Project [json#23.device_unique_id AS device_unique_id#25, json#23.signal_type AS signal_type#26, json#23.latitude AS latitude#27, json#23.longitude AS longitude#28, json#23.elevation AS elevation#29, json#23.timestamp AS timestamp#30]\n                  +- Project [jsontostructs(StructField(device_unique_id,StringType,true), StructField(signal_type,StringType,true), StructField(latitude,StringType,true), StructField(longitude,StringType,true), StructField(elevation,StringType,true), StructField(timestamp,StringType,true), value#21, Some(Asia/Kolkata)) AS json#23]\n                     +- Project [cast(value#8 as string) AS value#21]\n                        +- StreamingRelationV2 org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@49a5cdc2, kafka, Map(subscribe -> gpx_points_input, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> 172.17.9.26:9092), [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@611544,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(subscribe -> gpx_points_input, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> 172.17.9.26:9092),None), kafka, [key#0, value#1, topic#2, partition#3, offset#4L, timestamp#5, timestampType#6]\n'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

if I try with "complete" output mode, it says -

> Analysis Exception: Inner Join between two streaming dataframes/datasets is not supported in Complete mode, only in append mode.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any alternative way or a workaround?
Apologies for the type of question, I am new to spark.
Thanks.

Comment: What isn't clear about `not supported in Complete mode, only in append mode.` or `without watermark`?

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, Sir I really appreciate you responding to every question of mine on pyspark and helping me out although I am a huge beginner in this that I am not even much familiar with intermediate sql concepts. I read the error and tried the understand watermark and window functions and concepts but I couldn't understand how to use the concept in my case. With all due respect I am not requesting others on this community to write the code for me, I am just looking for directions how to resolve the error and/or the proper way to do the required task.

Comment: Also, in some article I found that joins are not supported in streaming dataframes (at all) that is why I was unsure. You being more experienced in this community would know how frustrating it is to get stuck on some error and unable to resolve it or have a workaround for it. I would again like to apologize for the immaturity of my question, I am just trying to understand how to get things done.

Comment: Well, I don't have much to any real experience with Spark Streaming, so best of luck to ya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here => http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#support-matrix-for-joins-in-streaming-queries Some joins aren't suported on streaming mode.

Maybe using a left outer join.

And writing in append mode should do the trick

```
SQL_QUERY = 'SELECT a.device_unique_id, a.signal_type, a.longitude, a.latitude, a.timestamp ' \
        'FROM table_max_ts b
         LEFT JOIN gps_table a ' \
        'ON b.timestamp==a.timestamp AND b.device_unique_id==a.device_unique_id'
```

**EDIT** : watermarking is needed to ensure looking to the rights data in a time maner. For outer joins

```
    filtered_gps_messagesW = filtered_gps_messages.withWatermark("timestamp", "2 hours")
    gps_messagesW= gps_messages.withWatermark("timestamp", "3 hours")
```

Then register you watermarked DS as tmpTables and you should be ok.Adjust time intervals to you need.

Comment: thanks for the reply, truly appreciate it. The above query, with append mode throws same error: >> "Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark". Shall I look into watermark concept?

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation. `append` mode works, while `complete` does not.